# Хук useState с callback'ом

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать кастомный хук `useStateWithCallback`. Есть код, который, судя по всему, должен работать, но он всё равно не выполняет свою задачу корректно:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export const useStateWithCallback = (initialState) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

    const isFirstLoad = useRef(true);
    const callbackFunction = useRef<Function>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isFirstLoad.current) {
            isFirstLoad.current = false;
            return;
        }

        callbackFunction.current?.(state);
    }, [state]);

    const setCallbackState = (updatedState, callback?: Function) => {
        callbackFunction.current = callback;
        setState(updatedState);
    }

    return [state, setCallbackState];
}
```

UPD: Выяснилась интересная вещь: этот способ работает, если делать то же самое, только без кастомного хука. То есть писать весь код из хука напрямую в компонент. Разумеется, это не совсем то, что нужно, однако теперь ясно, что проблема скорее всего в том, что обновление состояния внутри хука не приводит к перерисовке компонента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хук работает как нужно, просто у нас тесты не были валидны :)

```
const [state, setState] = useStateWithCallback(0);
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setState(
        state => state + 1, 
        (updatedState) => console.log(`Now state is ${updatedState}!`)
    ));
});
```